# IBM HeapAnalyzer wont open

Tags: websphere-commerce

I downloaded IBM Support Assistance Workbench, Installed HeapAnalyzer 4.5.4.  When I try and start the HeapAnalyzer tool I get this error:

```
Cannot Launch HeapAnalyzer - Could not find the main class: com.ibm.jinwoo.heap.HeapAnalyzer
Today 8:22 AM | Tags: heapanalyzer, installation, run
 Unanswered question This question has not been answered yet.
I cannot seem to launch HeapAnalyzer

C:\Software\IBMHeapAnalyzer>java -Xmx1g -jar ha454.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ibm/jinwoo/heap/HeapAnalyzer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.ibm.jinwoo.heap.HeapAnalyzer. Program will exit.
```

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to fix it?

Comment: what java version do you have on your machine? type java --version   does the version agree with 51.0 - refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0  you may need to install the latest jdk, or you can export the JAVA_HOME for the IBM JDK and add $JAVA_HOME/bin to your path

Comment: ahh thanks for pointing that out, if you create an answer ill mark it correct

Comment: no problem, I've had the issue before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type java --version does the version agree with 51.0

- refer to stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/…

you may need to install the latest jdk, or you can export the JAVA_HOME for the IBM JDK and add $JAVA_HOME/bin to your path